# Accesing unknown nested objects in a JSON using GROOVY

Tags: json, groovy

I have the following JSON from a response from a random REST request:

{ pages= { 56206384={ title = Siberia } }

how can I extract the element "title", given that the number 56206384 will change with every new request? is there a way to have a regex expression for any number?

already tried:  def title = ParsedResponse.query.pages.(*).title

any ideas? would appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> { pages= { 56206384={ title = Siberia } }
>
> how can I extract the element "title", given that the number 56206384
> will change with every new request?

If you know the structure will be just like what you have shown, you could do something like this.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper


def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = slurper.parseText '{ "pages": { "56206384" : { "title":  "Siberia" } }'

def title = json.pages.values().title[0]
```